# Visual effect with dark overlay gradient surrounding the center of the screen

Tags: graphic-effects

How is it called, what is it used for, and what is the most common way to implement it?

I know these are three question in one, but since the first and second are just one-liners I decided to make them into one.

The following images are two screenshots showing the visual effect; (A) show the zones that are darker and (B) the normal zones

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [vignetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting) effect. You can easily accomplish this with a [shader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caQZKeAYgD8).

Comment: +1. In the second screenshot, it might also just be a non-uniform lighting effect. Hard to tell with a still image and the cartoonish shading, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It could be the upper half of the vignette too